# rsync via gateway ssh while defining .pem key

Tags: networking, unix, rsync, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I need to sync my local files through a gateway to an Amazon EC2 instance that requires specifying my .pem key. I can do this as a three step like so (assuming no typos):

- `rsync -avzh -e ssh /my_site/ user@XX.XX.XX.XX:/temp_destination/`
- ssh to the gateway
- `rsync -avzh -e "ssh - My_Key.pem" temp_destination/ user@XX.XX.XX.XXX:/var/www`

I'd like to get this into one single command, but I'm wrestling through the flags and options and can't seem to get anything to work that lets me specify my `.pem` key.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can't answer my own question for another 7 hours, so in case I forget, I found the answer:

`rsync -avzh --stats --progress -e "ssh user@gatway.host ssh -i MY_KEY.pem" ~/Sites/my_site/ user@remote.server:/var/www/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, posting the answer for future devs.

```
rsync -avzh --stats --progress \
  -e "ssh user@gateway.host ssh -i My_Key.pem" \
   ~/Sites/my_site/ \ 
   user@ec2.host:/var/www/
```